# Django path missmatch

Tags: python, django, path

I have problem with my urls. Path of my site in localhost is:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/detska-kniznica

When I want to login I will click on the button and path looks like this:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/detska-kniznica/login

And when I will submit the form path looks like this:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/detska-kniznica/login/logUser

Problem is when I type incorrect password or username django returns forms to the same url so:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/detska-kniznica/login/logUser

And when I will again type correct username and password url looks like this:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/detska-kniznica/login/login/logUser and this url does not exist.

I will show you my urls:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('detska-kniznica', include('homepage.urls')),
    path('detska-kniznica/admin', admin.site.urls),
    path('detska-kniznica/games', include('games.urls')),
    path('detska-kniznica/register', include('register.urls')),
    path('detska-kniznica/login', include('login.urls')),
]
```

and

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('/logUser', views.log_user),
    path('/logOut', views.log_out_user),
]
```

my HTML submit button do this:

```
 <form action="login/logUser" method="post" novalidate>
```

and my views.py looks like this:

```
elif request.method == 'POST' and 'btn_login' in request.POST:
    form = inputForms.LogUser(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.errors)
        user_name = form.cleaned_data['username']
        user_password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=user_password)
        if user is not None:
            print("som tu")
            request.session.set_expiry(86400)  # sets the exp. value of the session
            login(request, user)  # the user is now logged in
        else:
            print("help")
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request, "login.html", {'LogUser': form})
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/detska-kniznica')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return render(request, "login.html", {'LogUser': form})
```

## line above shoul return /login but it returns /login/logUser and this is wrong

```
else:
    print("Error: bad request in login.")
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/detska-kniznica')
```

Any ideas please? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this piece of HTML:

```
<form action="login/logUser" method="post" novalidate>
```

which should be:

```
<form action="/login/logUser" method="post" novalidate>
```

If you don't have the leading `/` your browser assumes the URL is relative.

Comment: Thank you so much.